# How to disable Telerik datetime picker in ASP.Net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I am trying to make datetime picker readonly. I found the following code in the internet

```
  $("#RequestedDate").attr('disabled', true)
    .next("span.t-select")
    .children("span.t-icon-calendar").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

which works great but it reset datetime to minimun datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the "readonly" attribute, not "disabled".  If it's disabled the value won't be picked up.